# Register a kubelet into the kube-apiserver

Tags: kubernetes

**What I want to do:**

For my own educational purposes I'm trying to start a kube API server and register a kubelet as a node into it. I'm doing this exercise into a vagrant box which runs linux and a docker runtime.

**What I did so far is:**

1. I've run a dockerized etcd using the host network:

```
$docker run --volume=$PWD/etcd-data:/default.etcd --detach --net=host quay.io/coreos/etcd

$docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                 COMMAND                 CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
3f4a42fce24a        quay.io/coreos/etcd   "/usr/local/bin/etcd"   2 hours ago         Up 2 hours                              awesome_bartik
```

2. I've started the API server connecting it to etcd

```
$./kube-apiserver --etcd-servers=http://127.0.0.1:2379 --service-cluster-ip-range=10.0.0.0/16
```

The server v.1.16 is up and running as seen next:

```
$curl http://localhost:8080/version
{
  "major": "1",
  "minor": "16",
  "gitVersion": "v1.16.0",
  "gitCommit": "2bd9643cee5b3b3a5ecbd3af49d09018f0773c77",
  "gitTreeState": "clean",
  "buildDate": "2019-09-18T14:27:17Z",
  "goVersion": "go1.12.9",
  "compiler": "gc",
  "platform": "linux/amd64"
}
```

No nodes are registered yet.

**What I can't yet achieve:**

Now I want to start the kubelet and register it as a Node. In earlier versions this was maybe possible with the `--api-servers` flag but this flag is already removed and the configuration is supposed to be in a separate kubelet config file.

My question is how to configure the access to the API server in the kubelet configuration file?  Similar discussion is available [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/36745) but it did not help me too much. The kubelet configuration options are available [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubelet/blob/master/config/v1beta1/types.go).

So far the config file looks like this... Seems that `staticPodURL` is definitely not the right config :-)

```
kind: KubeletConfiguration
apiVersion: kubelet.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
staticPodURL: http://localhost:8080
failSwapOn: false
authentication:
  anonymous:
    enabled: true
  webhook:
    enabled: false
authorization:
  mode: AlwaysAllow
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a good amount of digging I've managed to make the kubelet register into the kube-api server which opens my way for further building of a small k8s cluster component by component.

The flag that I was looking for in the kubelet config is the following:

> --kubeconfig string
>
> Path to a kubeconfig file, specifying how to connect to the API server.  Providing --kubeconfig enables API server
> mode, omitting --kubeconfig enables standalone mode.

Now I have two config files:

```
$ cat 02.kubelet-api-server-config.yaml 
apiVersion: v1
kind: Config
clusters:
  - cluster:
      server: http://localhost:8080
    name: kubernetes
contexts:
  - context:
      cluster: kubernetes
    name: system:node:java2dayskube@kubernetes
current-context: system:node:java2dayskube@kubernetes
preferences: {}


$ cat 02.kubelet-base-config.yaml 
kind: KubeletConfiguration
apiVersion: kubelet.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
staticPodURL: http://localhost:8080
failSwapOn: false
authentication:
  anonymous:
    enabled: true
  webhook:
    enabled: false
authorization:
  mode: AlwaysAllow
```

As stated above the API server is up and running so I can start the kubelet now:

```
sudo ./kubelet --config=02.kubelet-base-config.yaml --kubeconfig=02.kubelet-api-server-config.yaml
```

Obviously the kubelet registered itself as a node in the API server (details skipped for brevity):

```
$ curl http://localhost:8080/api/v1/nodes
{
  "kind": "NodeList",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {
    "selfLink": "/api/v1/nodes",
    "resourceVersion": "62"
  },
  "items": [
    {
      "metadata": {
        "name": "vagrant",
        ...
        "creationTimestamp": "2019-11-03T09:12:18Z",
        "labels": {
          "beta.kubernetes.io/arch": "amd64",
          "beta.kubernetes.io/os": "linux",
          "kubernetes.io/arch": "amd64",
          "kubernetes.io/hostname": "vagrant",
          "kubernetes.io/os": "linux"
        },
        "annotations": {
          "volumes.kubernetes.io/controller-managed-attach-detach": "true"
        }
      },
      "spec": {
        "taints": [
          {
            "key": "node.kubernetes.io/not-ready",
            "effect": "NoSchedule"
          }
        ]
      }
      ...
}
```

I've managed to create one pod by making a POST request to the api-server. The kubelet was notified and span the corresponding docker containers.